# Can Qmake accept custom arguments?

Tags: qt, qmake

I've been working on a program called RoboJournal for some time now and I'm trying to simplify the creation of source packages for Debian. When a user builds the program on Linux, qmake sets the install path to /usr/local/bin (which is as it should be for user-compiled programs) However, this causes problems when I create the Debian source package since all packaged executables are supposed to install to /usr/bin.

The easiest way to fix this problem is to edit the install path manually before making the source package but I would prefer to keep the codebase the same (having multiple variants of the codebase with the same version number always causes problems eventually).

It would be great if the package maintainer could just run something like `qmake --package robojournal.pro` to create a makefile with the correct install path for packaging purposes. Meanwhile, omitting the `--package` argument would still allow users to create a regular build.

Can this (or something similar) be done?   I've checked the qmake documentation but I’ve found nothing on configuring a project file to allow  qmake to accept custom Unix-style arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve what you need by using the [CONFIG variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html#generalconfiguration). Anything can be added to the CONFIG variable and each of the options specified in the CONFIG variable can be used as a scope condition:

```
package {
    message(Creating a makefile with the correct install path for packaging purposes...)
} else {
    message(Creating a regular build...)
}
```

This provides you with a convenient way to customize project files and fine-tune the generated Makefiles. See [Configuration and Scopes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#configuration-and-scopes).

The list of values held by CONFIG can be extended on the command line. You can run qmake with or without "CONFIG+=package":

```
qmake "CONFIG+=package" robojournal.pro

qmake robojournal.pro
```

See [Makefile Mode Options](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html#makefile-mode-options).

Comment: Can I specify `LIBS` and/or `INCLUDEPATH` arguments too? If so, how do I deal with paths requiring quotes?

Comment: @Troyseph Why would you specify `LIBS` or `INCLUDEPATH` arguments on the command line? It sounds strange.

Comment: long story, a temporary measure I assure you! I managed it in the QtCreator qmake buld step, using single quotes around the paths and double quotes aroung each XXX+=Y Y Y

Answer (score 1):

By default `qmake` produces empty `install` and `unistall` targets unless you instruct `qmake` to do install explicitly.

For example, the project file

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

results in the following Makefile (only install part is shown to save the space)

```
####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

Then the following rule in Qt project file will specify installation path

```
unix {
    target.path = /usr/bin/

    INSTALLS += target
}
```

Now Makefile has changed

```
####### Install

install_target: first FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/bin/ || $(MKDIR) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/bin/ 
-$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) "$(QMAKE_TARGET)" "$(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/bin/$(QMAKE_TARGET)"

uninstall_target:  FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) "$(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/bin/$(QMAKE_TARGET)"
-$(DEL_DIR) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/bin/ 

install:  install_target  FORCE

uninstall: uninstall_target   FORCE

FORCE:
```

This is the part from robojournal.pro:

```
target.path = /usr/local/bin

INSTALLS += target shortcut icon shortcut-deb icon-deb
```

End users will highly unlikely to compile application. And even those who will compile it like me, won't install it, because it can be launched from build directory. Thus, it's safe to replace /usr/local/bin with /usr/bin.